# Bug?: Repeat activities won't accept edits after 4.7.31 upgrade

Tags: activities, issues

We've noticed that we cannot edit recurring activities after upgrading to 4.7.31 on WordPress 4.9.4 running PHP 5.6.34.

On making a change to any activity in a series and hitting "Save", we get the usual three options:

**How should this change affect others in the series?**

- Only this activity
- This activity onwards
- Every activity

However, on selection, none of the options are working and the system continues to display the activity in editing mode.

This also is the case if we try to delete the Activity by clicking delete here:

[image]

Attempting to delete in this fashion also brings up the same non-working 3 radio buttons noted above.

HOWEVER, we do note that if we select a checkbox in a list of activities, we *can* successfully delete the single activity.

In short, none of the radio buttons that appear after trying to edit/delete an Activity during its view seem to work anymore and, as such, a series of activities cannot be modified after creation, accept for deleting en masse via checkbox commands.

Troubleshooting suggestions appreciated.

Comment: We are also experiencing this issue on the same versions of you are on in relation to updating events. First noticed this occurring on 4.7.30. This is the error: https://pastebin.com/kgfWrds1

Comment: Thank you. Has anyone done a patch? I do notice that functionality is correct on 5.1Alpha1 test site.

Comment: it's likely it has been patched - 5.0 is due out this week - you can upgrade to it now if you want by grabbing the tarball from https://download.civicrm.org/latest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After creating/saving an activity, re-opening it to edit won't allow links and drop-downs to be changed](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26432/after-creating-saving-an-activity-re-opening-it-to-edit-wont-allow-links-and-d)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

We're still having the issue with 5.4.2 and I've made a better thread here since my observations may not have been expressed clearly.

[After creating/saving an activity, re-opening it to edit won't allow links and drop-downs to be changed](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26432/after-creating-saving-an-activity-re-opening-it-to-edit-wont-allow-links-and-d)

Suggest future discussion occur at that link and this be closed.